# ProGuard can't find classes when compiling release apk

Tags: android, proguard, android-volley

I have a problem with proguard and volley library(https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley). it builds well in debug mode but in release, it gives an error. I've tried all the solutions on Stackoverflow but none worked for me. Here's the error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:proguardRelease
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpClientStack]
  Method      = [performRequest(Lcom/android/volley/Request;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/apache/http/HttpResponse;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/android/volley/Request] (with 2 known super classes) and [com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpClientStack$HttpPatch] (with 1 known super classes))
Exception while processing task 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/android/volley/Request] (with 2 known super classes) and [com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpClientStack$HttpPatch] (with 1 known super classes)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.findCommonClass(TypedReferenceValue.java:441)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.generalize(TypedReferenceValue.java:277)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.generalize(TypedReferenceValue.java:201)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:298)
    at proguard.evaluation.Variables.generalize(Variables.java:136)
    at proguard.evaluation.TracedVariables.generalize(TracedVariables.java:118)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:690)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:609)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:567)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:271)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:188)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseChecker.visitCodeAttribute(SimpleEnumUseChecker.java:115)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:81)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:92)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:73)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:516)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseChecker.visitProgramClass(SimpleEnumUseChecker.java:102)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:358)
    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
    at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:389)
    at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:328)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:127)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:app:dexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateExternalOverrideSigning
:app:packageRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of C:\Users\MyName\AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 37.612 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is my setting in proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
```

Comment: does it also happen if you add `android {useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}` to your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Could you please post your `build.gradle` script? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep volley library the following :

```
-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing this line in my build.gradle:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt")
```

The default rules contain the rule

> -dontoptimize

which was the main cause for the error